# Error in my code Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to programming.
I wrote a code to fetch last added record but it throwing an error.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fetch.php on line 17 0 results

fetch.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "d4rky";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM data ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["dataset"]. " " . $row["datamet"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Table name : data

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Is `SELECT TOP 1` valid for mysql?

Comment: You are using `SQL Server / MS Access Syntax` inside mysql which is wrong, you can use `SELECT * FROM data ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: The main problem is that you assume your sql query is correct and you do not check for errors. Had you done so, you would know what went wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing sql server syntax with mysql.

`SELECT TOP 1` is used in sql server. In mysql you have to use `Limit` to get specific number of records like.

`SELECT field1,fileld2,field3 FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

OR to fecth all fields simply use

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `SQL` syntax in `MYSQL`, change your query to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1";
```